# My experiments to my body

Tags: muscle-gain, exercise-technique, muscle-recovery, exercise-frequency

I'm doing an experiment with my own body. Experiment is such that -

1. Do push ups until your you fall on the ground and cannot push your body up further. Do squats until your legs vibrate very fast. Do sit ups until you can't sit up anymore. Write your number of reps of each exercise in your phone or copy.
2. Rest until your body fully recover. It can take roughly 3-5 days or even less or more.
3. After step 2 done, repeat step 1 You must be able to do more reps than before. Repeat step 2 then 3.

My goal from this experiment is to reach my maximum limit. I call it saturation reps, at this point no matter how long you rest, your body cannot do more than this maximum reps. After reaching this limit, I want to do this saturation reps every 6 working days in a week.

Will it grow my muscles? What are your assumptions based on scientific facts?

I'm 19yo. My height is approximately 5'3ft. Weight is very low i.e. 43-45kg.

Answer (score 7):

#### Your exercise selection leaves much to be desired.

Your routine consists of only three movements: push-ups, squats, and sit-ups. The primary muscles targeted then are the triceps, anterior delts, pecs, rectus abdominis, and quadriceps. You are essentially doing nothing to work the entire back half of your body - hamstrings, glutes, erector spinae, lats, traps, rear delts, and biceps. Ideally, we would like to see a resistance training routine be more complete than this, having at least a squat pattern, a lower pull or hip hinge, a push pattern, and an upper pull or row.

#### Your chosen rep range likely provides insufficient resistance to stimulate significant hypertrophy.

You will see some growth. Going from doing nothing to doing something is generally going to be enough to stimulate *some* amount hypertrophy, but your muscles will adapt to the exercise you put them through. Your chosen scheme, very high rep with no external loading, is simply not going to produce any significant muscle hypertrophy, because contractile tissue is not the adaptation required for the work being done. You will likely see excellent return on endurance and recovery adaptations, because that is what you are selecting for. You don't have to be that much stronger to go from 20 pushups to 40, you just have to train your muscles to be efficient.

If you want to see any significant muscle hypertrophy, you need to expose your muscles to higher loads at lower rep ranges, the generally accepted "optimal" rep range for hypertrophy is 8-15, depending on the movement and muscle group.

#### You can get *more* quality work in by stopping short of muscle failure.

You don't have to go to failure on a movement to see results. In fact, it may be detrimental to progress if going to failure means you sacrifice total volume. If stopping a few reps short of failure means you can get several quality sets in, then you will likely see much greater benefit from a few challenging sets than one set to failure. Further, this lets you manage overall fatigue better, and allows you quicker recovery. If it take five days to recover from your workout, then you have a six day pattern: one day on five days off.  If you instead manage your fatigue by stopping short of failure, you could shorten your recovery time to only one day, and get three workouts in six days, yielding much higher total volume for a similar total fatigue cost.

#### Think about what your goal is.

If you goal is simply to be able to do alarmingly high numbers of pushups, body squats, and crunches, then you're doing the right thing. But those are really the only adaptations you have selected for. If your goals are more aligned with strength or muscle hypertrophy, then this routine is simply going to be insufficient. You have to tell your body that it needs to increase its volume of contractile tissue in order for your body to increase its volume of contractile tissue, and your routine isn't going to send that signal; again, this is okay if hypertrophy isn't really your goal.